# Cursor returns null in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, android-cursor

The cursor in my method getHighScore() is returning a null value and I'm not sure why. I've used

```
system.out.println(cursor.moveToFirst());
```

and it prints false. When I run the query in SQLiteman, it returns a result.

Here is my whole class. I've put dummy data in for the package.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

// Static Database Information
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quiz_db.db";
public final static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.app/databases/quiz_db.db";
private static final String QUESTION_TABLE = "Questions";
private static final String SCORE_TABLE = "Score";

// Questions Table Column Names
private static final String Q_ID = "id";
private static final String Q_QUESTION = "question";
private static final String Q_ANSWER1 = "answer_one";
private static final String Q_ANSWER2 = "answer_two";
private static final String Q_ANSWER3 = "answer_three";
private static final String Q_ANSWER4 = "answer_four";
private static final String Q_CORRECT = "correct_answer";


// Score Table Column Names
private static final String S_ID = "id";
private static final String S_SCORE = "score";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_QUESTION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + QUESTION_TABLE + "("
            + Q_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Q_QUESTION + " TEXT,"
            + Q_ANSWER1 + " TEXT" + Q_ANSWER2 + " TEXT" + Q_ANSWER3 + " TEXT" + Q_ANSWER4 + " TEXT" + Q_CORRECT + " TEXT" + 
            ")";

    String CREATE_SCORE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + SCORE_TABLE + "("
            + S_ID + " INTEGER," + S_SCORE + " INTEGER"
            + ")";


    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUESTION_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SCORE_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + QUESTION_TABLE);

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SCORE_TABLE);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

// Get High Score
public int getHighScore () {
    int score = 0;
    String query = "SELECT score FROM " + SCORE_TABLE + ";";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         score = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("score"));
    }

    cursor.close();
    return score;

}
```

My database is in the "assets" folder and the file name is "quiz_db.db"

Comment: So your score table doesn't contain any rows.

Comment: When I run the same query in Sqliteman, it returns a row which is the result I am trying to get. So my score table does contain a row.

Comment: Likely you aren't running the queries on the same database file.

Comment: You are not using the database in the assets folder.

Comment: Okay, how can I run the queries on the same database file or copy the assets database to the path?